# Examples how to save file from external .Net application to Sharepoint

Tags: c#, .net, angular, sharepoint-2010

I need to save files from the existing AngularJS/.NET application to Sharepoint. Most of the examples I see online is when applications reside on Sharepoint itself. How do I save files from outside?

I've been given a user access to our organization's Sharepoint site but no application user passwords. What do I need to request from administrators of SharePoint site to be able to write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use CSOM C# code to upload file to SharePoint 2010 document library. We need use an admin user and password to pass the Credentials in the .NET application server.

```
public static void UploadFile(ClientContext context, string uploadFolderUrl, string uploadFilePath)
{
    var fileCreationInfo = new FileCreationInformation
    {
        Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadFilePath),
        Overwrite = true,
        Url = Path.GetFileName(uploadFilePath)
    };
    var targetFolder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(uploadFolderUrl);
    var uploadFile = targetFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInfo);
    context.Load(uploadFile);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var siteUrl="http://sp2010";
var username="admin";
var password="xx";
var domainName="domain1";
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    ctx.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password, domainName);
    UploadFile(ctx,"Documents/folder1",@"c:\upload\test.docx");
}
```

The following article for your reference.

[Uploading files using Client Object Model in SharePoint 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Thank you! I haven't been given admin passwords, so I am getting unauthorized messages back. Is there a sandbox server developers can use to try the code? (We used to be able to do that for box.com)